# Import data into Cassandra using docker in window

Tags: docker, cassandra

Hi i am trying to load into cassandra in docker. Unfortunately, i can't make it. I pretty sure the path is correct, as i directly copy and paste from the properties section. May i know is there any alternative to solve it?

p.s. i am using windows 11, latest cassandra 4.1

```
cqlsh:cds502_project> COPY data (id)
                  ... FROM 'D:\USM\Data Science\CDS 502 Big data storage and management\Assignment\Project\forest area by state.csv' 
                  ... WITH HEADER = TRUE; 
Using 7 child processes

Starting copy of cds502_project.data with columns [id].
Failed to import 0 rows: OSError - Can't open 'D:\\USM\\Data Science\\CDS 502 Big data storage and management\\Assignment\\Project\\forest area by state.csv' for reading: no matching file found,  given up after 1 attempts
Processed: 0 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       0 rows/s
0 rows imported from 0 files in 0.246 seconds (0 skipped).
```

above is my code and the result. I have tried https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/export-and-import-data-in-cassandra/ exactly and it works when i create the data inside the docker, export and reimport it, but not working when i use external data.

I also notice the csv file i exported using cassandra in docker is missing in my laptop but can be access by docker.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour you are observing is what is expected from docker. What I know there are cp commands in Kubernetes which copy the data from outside to inside container and vice-versa. Either you can check those commands to take the data from inside or outside the docker or other way is you can push your csv into docker using a Docker Image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you need to leverage Docker bind mounting a volume in order to access local files within your container. `docker run -it -v <path> ...`

See references below:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host
- https://www.docker.com/blog/file-sharing-with-docker-desktop/